# Union forcing initiation of all members, not only active one?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I have the following code (with some unnecessary details removed):

Header:

```
enum class TargetType : uint8
{
    NoTarget
    , Location
    , Actor
};


class Target
{
public:

    Target();
    Target(const FVector &inLocation);
    Target(const AActor *inTargetActor);

    // ... some methods here

private:

    TargetType targetType;

    union
    {
        FVector location;
        TWeakObjectPtr<AActor> targetActor;
    };
};
```

Source:

```
// ... header includes

Target::Target()
    : targetType { TargetType::NoTarget }
{
}

Target::Target(const FVector &inLocation)
    : targetType { TargetType::Location }
    , location(inLocation)
{
}

Target::Target(const AActor *inTargetActor)
    : targetType { TargetType::Actor }
    , targetActor(inTargetActor)
{
}

// ... some code
```

When I try to compile this I get the following errors:

```
error C4582: 'Target::location': constructor is not implicitly called
error C4582: 'Target::targetActor': constructor is not implicitly called
error C4582: 'Target::targetActor': constructor is not implicitly called
error C4582: 'Target::location': constructor is not implicitly called
```

The compiler complains about the union members not being initiated. The first constructor complains about both members not being initiated. The other two complains about the member not being initiated, so e.g. if I want to use the `Target::location`, the compiler wants me to initiate the `Target::targetActor` as well.

Do I really have to initiate both members if I'm not going to use them, e.g. in the first constructor? For me it makes no sense since I don't want to use the data in that case? Also why do I have to initiate `Target::location` when I want to use `Target::targetActor` as the active member? I'm I missing something here?

Comment: if you need both, then why an union and not a struct??

Comment: Thanks for your reply! To clarify, I don't need them simultaneously.

Comment: It's a level 4 warning, and it is telling the truth. :-)  If you don't like the info, just disable the warning.

Comment: looks like it's better to use std::optional if you can.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks a lot! Disabling the warning did the trick!

Comment: Line numbers (or which line the error is on) are important to errors.

Comment: As an aside, this looks like a `std::variant`.  I'd recomment finding an implementation of `std::variant` with a permissive license and using it rather than rolling your own.